# Invalid object name 'dbo.EdmMetadata' and 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 and doing a simple query to get a few users from a table.

The SQL database is already created so I use my entities as a way to map what I have.

When I run my query I detect that other queries were executed and 2 of them with errors:

**QUERY 1**

> ERROR: Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.

```
SELECT
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( 
    SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
) AS [GroupBy1]
```

**QUERY 2**

> ERROR: Invalid object name 'dbo.EdmMetadata'.

```
SELECT TOP (1)
   [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
   [Extent1].[ModelHash] AS [ModelHash]
FROM [dbo].[EdmMetadata] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC
```

Why is that?

I do not have `dbo.EdmMetadata` and `dbo.__MigrationHistory` tables in my database as the database already existed.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 60):

Since the database is already there you will not have `dbo.EdmMetadata` and `dbo.__MigrationHistory` which codefirst is expecting.  And to resolve this you can try to set the `SetInitializer` to null.

```
 static NameOfYourContext()
 {
   Database.SetInitializer<NameOfYourContext>(null);        
 }
```

You can see this in the comments section of the this post by [**Scott Gu**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx#7579835)

Comment: Works great. Note that your constructor may not be `static`, and the above code doesn't exist with a non-null argument -- you'll have to add the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 steps you need to follow:

1- Enable migrations in package manager if you haven't done yet:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

2- Add a migration and make sure to use the -IgnoreChanges switch as you already have an existing database:

```
Add-Migration InitialModel -IgnoreChanges
```

3- Update the database. This will automatically create __MigrationHistory table for you.

```
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

I disabled my exception setting. and it overlooked this exception and went on to create these tables for me automatically

Comment: Pls provide code sample on how you "disabled exception setting". Otherwise it's not a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Environment: ADO.net physical data model, import from database code first, Entity Framework Ver.6.0, Visual Studio 2022, C#

Story: I have been plagued by the dbo.EdmMetadata & dbo.__MigrationHistory table missing exception(not visible, but shown in debug terminal, and will have trouble if SQL accessing account is without create table permission), search the net but all I found is the "Database.SetInitializer(null)" solution, which doesn't really fit in the code in its original form. no matter how I tried to modify it.

Result:
After hours of fumbling, I actually saved by ChatGPT (although gave me many unsuccessful suggestions first), the following is the solution, should applied to Entity Framework Ver.6 and above:

1. Create the following class(NameOfYourContext is the class name of your database model)

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDatabaseInitializer<NameOfYourContext>(null);
    }
}
```

2.Put the following code in your program entry point(for Winform application, program.cs -> Main function)

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MyDbConfiguration());
```

Hope this answer will be helpful.