# How do I prevent EF CodeFirst from trying to run migrations on my database, when configuring dependency injection with Unity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, unity-container, entity-framework-migrations

How do I prevent CodeFirst from trying to run migrations on my database?

I am getting `SqlException` thrown with the following error message:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.
```

These exceptions are being caught and logged by my logging framework. I need to prevent the exception from happening so lots of spurious log messages aren't generated by my application.

I understand the `__MigrationHistory` table is part of Code First Migrations. I **do** use Code First, but I **do not** use its migrations. (The project uses [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) instead.) According to [this blog post](http://nishitvaghela.blogspot.com/2015/06/invalid-object-name-dbomigrationhistory.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384007/645511), to disable the error, I need to do the following:

```
static InstitutionContext()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<InstitutionContext>(null);
}
```

(This, of course, for a `DbContext` object named `InstitutionContext`.)

I have done this, and verified that the line of code is getting hit. However, I am still getting the error in the logs.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895515/645511) explains what is happening, and I think it is basically correct. In short, EF is probing the `__MigrationsHistory` table, throws an exception when it doesn't find it, and then continues without doing anything with migrations. But the answer does not explain how to suppress the exception from happening.

How do I prevent the EF Code First migrations from trying to run and throwing its `SqlException`?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried configuring the setting via the App.config/Web.config file, and that didn't work either. I also tried moving it from a static method on my `DbContext` to its own configuration class, like this:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDatabaseInitializer<InstitutionContext>(null);
    }
}
```

The class is in the same assembly as the `DbContext` like it's supposed to be. This didn't work either.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem turned out to be related to the Unity container, and how EF and Unity were interacting given how I had both configured. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519492/645511) below.

Comment: Have you tried the `disableDatabaseInitialization` attribute?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606#Initializers

Comment: I've tried that, but I am not sure I've put it in the right place. I've put it in the Web.config of the web project, but this loads through Azure, so I'm not sure if that changes something. Is there any way to do that through code instead of a config file?

Comment: That should work depending on how the projects are structured. Here is an alternative method: https://romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments to my question note, what I was doing should work. The problem turned out to be with how my project was using the Unity dependency injection container.

For all types that were being registered, I was also configuring a virtual method interceptor. I was registering and configuring my `DbContext` like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IInstitutionContext, InstitutionContext>();
Container.Configure<Interception>()
    .SetInterceptorFor(typeof(InstitutionContext), 
        new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
```

The problem was the `VirtualMethodInterceptor`. The interceptor was causing the `InstitutionContext` class to be wrapped.

Entity Framework 6 maintains a registry associating a `DbContext` type to its configured `DbInitializer`. When it sees a new type of `DbContext` for the first time, it looks in its internal registry to see which `DbInitializer` should be called. It tries to find the `DbInitializer` based on the `DbContext`'s type. If it doesn't find a registered `DbInitializer`, it uses the default initializer, which is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`.

But when the `VirtualMethodInterceptor` is configured for a given `DbContext` type (in my case, `InstitutionContext`), the Unity container won't instantiate the `InstitutionContext` directly. Instead it wraps `InstitutionContext` in order to be able to intercept the virtual methods. When EF6 tries to locate the type to look up its `DbInitializer`, it checks the type of the DbContext, which is a wrapped type, **NOT** the `InstitutionContext` type. So it never finds a matching type, and falls back to using the default database initializer.

Removing the interceptor for the `DbContext` types fixed the problem.

**tl;dr:** Make sure your `DbContext` isn't wrapped by another type. For EF6's `DbInitializer` configuration to work, it must be checking the right `DbContext` type. It won't work if the `DbContext` is inherited from a type that has a registered `DbInitializer`, and it won't work if the `DbContext` is a wrapper type.