# Uncatchable errors from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement a basic example of Entity Framework, using the *Code First* approach, with an external database. I just want to read some already existing data, from a table in my database. The way I have implemented it works, in the sense that it shows the right output, but it throws a bunch of exceptions during the process. I have located the line of code, during which the exceptions are thrown, but I cannot catch them, using try/catch (see code).

Here is a screen dump of the Output log (debug) when I run the program (I have highlighted the final output with pink):
[image]

And here is a screen dump of the table I am connecting to:
[image]

Even though the output is correct, the errors do seem to affect the performance. It takes somewhere between 2-3 seconds to run the code, even though the table only contains six columns and three rows.

What I have done wrong, to make it behave like this?

**CODE**

The function which uses the EF-connection:

```
public PrintFirstEmployeeName()
{
    try
    {
        UniContext db = new UniContext();

        // Exceptions are thrown during this line of code:
        string fullName = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault().first_name 
                  + " " + db.Employees.FirstOrDefault().last_name; 

        Debug.WriteLine($"Hello { fullName }!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The employee model (names are matching database names 1:1):

```
[Table("dbo.sandbox_employee")]
public class EmployeeModel
{
    [Key]
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int company_id { get; set; }
}
```

The `dbContext` implementation:

```
public class UniContext : DbContext
{
    public UniContext() : base("Name=MyConnString") { }
    public DbSet<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnString" connectionString="Integrated Security = SSPI; Persist Security Info = False; Data Source = MyServer; Database = MyDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
  </startup>

  <entityFramework>

    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">

      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </parameters>

    </defaultConnectionFactory>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>

</entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

**ERRORS**

As far as I can tell, there are 3 different errors. All of them are thrown multiple times...

1. `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll`
2. `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll`
3. `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`

Comment: Don't see connection string...

Comment: @JohnyL someone broke the code, while editing the question. It is there again...

Comment: Do you have original T-SQL used to create that table?

Comment: EF Is generally slow the first time it is loaded into the application domain. This is a one time cost that is incurred when you  first use it. As far as catching the Exceptions: do you have the checkbox to catch all CLR Exceptions checked (CTRL+ALT+E = Check on 'Common Language Runitem Exceptions')

Comment: @JohnyL unfortunately not. But I have added a screen dump for SQL Server Management Studio, if that helps.

Comment: This would be helpful (with all subfolders expanded - Keys, Constraints etc.)

Comment: @Igor thanks, I did not know that option. Now I found an exception called `Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.`, whatever that means...

Comment: See [Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory' using Database.Create; EF6.02 when connection string is passed in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895515/1260204) for that exception

Comment: Try `[Table("sandbox_employee", "dbo")]`

Comment: Also run your application in Release mode without the debugger attached. Chances are it is much faster than in debug mode with the debugger.

Comment: First of all, I know there is a lot of undesirable things in my code, but I am only looking for the things which causes the errors. I have not been able to avoid the errors, by changing it to release. The linked post is helpful at explaining things, but it doesn't really help me solve the problem, which appears to be, that EF is looking for a table, which is not there...

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @JohnyL yep, that didnt help either. I had to write it like this though: `[Table("sandbox_employee", Schema = "dbo")]`.

Comment: I ran your code (without any changes at all) - and got **no** errors...

Comment: @JohnyL thanks. It is probably related to the creation of the database then and perhaps the external database. Problem is that I need to work with that specific database and even some tables and views on it, which are even older an more hopelessly build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170530/discussion-between-johnyl-and-noceo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two tables `dbo.__MigrationHistory` and `dbo.EdmMetadata` is (usually) not there for existing databases. Entity Framework (EF) looks for these tables during initialization, which causes the exceptions I saw. Setting the initialization to `null` right after instantiating the `DbContext` will tell EF not to look for these tables and no exceptions will occur.

```
using (UniContext db = new UniContext())
{
    Database.SetInitializer<UniContext>(null); // Prevents initialization exceptions

    var emp = db.Employees.First();

    Debug.WriteLine($"Hello { emp.FirstName } { emp.LastName }!");
}
```

- See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379956/invalid-object-name-dbo-edmmetadata-and-dbo-migrationhistory) for more details.
- Thanks to @JohnyL for helping me solve the mystery.